# Which graph to use for unequal class widths AND huge frequency range

Tags: data-visualization, frequency

I recently saw a question where they wanted us to plot an appropriate graph for classes of unequal widths, starting from 0. Normally, we'd have used histogram but then the frequencies ranged from 33 to 7446. I've no idea how to incorporate so many values in the Y-axis. Will this Q really be solved by a histogram? If yes, please explain how to plot it and if no, what graph to use and what exactly to do next?

Comment: The frequencies have a wide range. What is the problem with displaying this fact? // Do you mean that one group has many more observations, so the red histogram is tall while the blue histogram is short?

Comment: It is usually best to use equal interval widths; break this "rule" only for good reason.

Answer (score 3):

Shown below are a data summary, frequency histogram, and boxplot of a sample of size $n = 100$ from an exponential population with mean $\mu = 1000$ (rate $\lambda = 1/\mu = 0.001).$ These data may be something like yours.

```
set.seed(2021)  # use same seed to get same data
x = rexp(100, 0.001)

summary(x); length(x); sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  10.99  282.63  708.81 1000.57 1285.20 4699.93 
[1] 100         # sample size
[1] 1035.345    # sample standard deviation

hdr = "Sample of 100 from Exponential Dist'n with Mean 1000"
hist(x, ylim=c(0,40), col="skyblue3", main=hdr)
 abline(h = seq(10,30,by=10), col="white", lwd=2)
```

[image]

```
boxplot(x, horizontal=T, col="skyblue3", pch=20)
```

[image]